# Prove every element of $R$ determines an $E$-endomorphism of $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This problem taken from Hartley-Hawkes's Book (Rings, Modules, and Linear Algebra), exercises for Chapter 5 pp. 83 number 12.

> Let $M$ be any $R$-module and let $E=\operatorname{End}_R M$ be the
> set of $R$-endomorphism of $M$. Show that definitions \begin{align}
>  (\eta_1+\eta_2)(m)=\eta_1(m)+\eta_2(m)\\
> (\eta_1\eta_2)(m)=\eta_1(\eta_2(m))\\ \end{align} for all
> $\eta_1,\eta_2\in E$ and $m\in M$ make $E$ into ring. Show that $M$
> can be regarded as an $E$-module and that every element of $R$
> determines an $E$-endomorphism of $M$.

I have proved $E$ as ring and $M$ is an $E$-module. Now I want to prove third question, i.e. every element of $R$ determines an $E$-endomorphism of $M$.

The elements of $R$ is not a mapping. My question is: how can we prove every element of $R$ determines an $E$-endomorphism of $M$? I know to show it we must prove every element of $R$ is $E$-homomorphism from $M$ into $M$. But the elements of $R$ is not a mapping, can we prove every element of $R$ is $E$-homomorphism from $M$ into $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r\in R$, look at $m_r\colon x\mapsto rx, x\in M$. Given any $f\in E, m_r(f(x)) = rf(x) = f(rx) = f(m_r(x))$, so $m_r$ is an $E$-endomorphism.